# How to add ToolStripMenuItems dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip, menustrip

```
sqlstr = "select ModuleName,ModuleId,pagename from modules WHERE ParentID='" + parentID + "' AND VIsibility=1 ORDER BY ModuleId";

cmd.CommandText = sqlstr;
cmd.Connection = cn; ;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    menu.Tag = dr["ModuleId"].ToString();
    menu.Text = dr["ModuleName"].ToString();
    menu.Name = dr["pagename"].ToString();
    menu.ToolTipText = dr["pagename"].ToString();
    menuStrip1.Items.Add(menu);
    menuStrip1.Show();
}

cn.Close();
dr.Close();
```

adding only last item from the query.how to add all the items from the query

Comment: also u need not close the reader if u r closing the connection, it gets disposed automatically. But you shoud close readers always as a part of good coding habit, which makes sense only if u do it before closing connection

Answer (score 3):

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    // If you don't do this, you are just changing the same
    // ToolStripMenuItem object all the time.
    menu = new ToolStripMenuItem();

    menu.Tag = dr["ModuleId"].ToString();
    menu.Text = dr["ModuleName"].ToString();
    menu.Name = dr["pagename"].ToString();
    menu.ToolTipText = dr["pagename"].ToString();
    menuStrip1.Items.Add(menu);
    menuStrip1.Show();
}
```

Comment: @KeithS You next step is using Command Parameters and the `using` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new ToolStripMenuItem in the loop each time. You just keep overwriting properties on the same menu instance.

Answer (score 0):

try making a new instance of the menu everytime your read a new row.

Something like this:

```
 while (dr.Read())
 {
    var menu = new ToolStripMenuItem();

    ...
 }
```